# Action when a YouTube video is posted in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'd like to write a Discord Bot that will send a message in a specific channel when a YouTube video is posted. In short, the flow is the following:

- Youtuber A posts a video
- Bot sends a message

I've seen the [push notificaions docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) but haven't been able to work much out yet. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you don't have to use a discord bot for that, you can do it with a webhook

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Is there a way to do this without the youtube accounts that I want to be monitoring being mine? I've looked into zapier, and I think I need to own the account to be able to add that webhook.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: [here's](https://gist.github.com/methdev/2e82914189c072231855002ccd21f18c) a link that might help